# I can't see icons of anticon anticon-star (ant design) in ios, in android it works perfect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-rating

Use a react ([rc-rate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-rate)) library, which is a rating and an icon is placed in the classname in the props called Character, the truth is that this works perfectly for me on Android and web, but on iOS, you see some squares, like no take the style or something. If someone can help me it would be of great help !!

**This is how it looks on iOS:**

[image]

**But on android it looks good:**

[image]

Do some research and try adding this line:

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css';`

But it was useless, the only thing it did is that neither the stars nor the squares that were seen before are seen.

[image]

**Here my code below:**

```
    <Fragment>
      <div className="container-surveys">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        {subtitle && <h4>{subtitle}</h4>}
        <Rate 
          character={<i className="anticon anticon-star" />}
          style={styleStarRating}
          onChange={onChangeRate}
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
```

Comment: Is this happening on Chrome IOS and Safari IOS? Or just Safari?

Comment: Works perfect on web (chrome, safari, mozilla, brave)
On android, it just doesn't work on iPhone

Comment: Did you try from different iPhones? Some times your Ad blockers or some other add-ons can cause trouble.

Comment: Yes iPhone (6plus, 11 and 12 pro max), same problem :/

Comment: Are you adding ant icons using @font-face? Can you share the code for that part?

Comment: No I'm not doing it for font-face, just
npm install antd
and in fact before I used it without that, without doing the npm or placing the css and it worked, only with
<i className = "anticon anticon-star" />

Comment: what's the version of antd in your project?

Comment: "antd": "^4.16.13",

Comment: Why don't you try using their icons like https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-16-13-forked-n3wcl?file=/index.js?

Comment: I'll try! And I'll tell you how I'm doing